# Angular chart not rendering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, angular-chart

I'm using the [Angular Charts](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/#bar-chart) to draw a bar graph in my application. However the chart is not rendering. There are no errors shown in the dev tools too.

Edit:

However i notice that the styles of angular-chart.css are not getting applied.

```
<canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar" chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

This is bound to my main controller and the values are defined as below

```
$scope.labels = ['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012'];
$scope.data = [
[65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
];
```

Edit:

angular.module('app', ['chart.js']);

I've added all the dependencies. Including the javascript files and css.
Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you declare the dependency? ``angular.module('myModule', ['chart.js']);`` Rest of your HTML/JS would help.

Comment: What css are you ready to apply? It's a canvas. Not DOM or SVG library.

Comment: The angular-chart.css classes aren't getting applied is what i meant @vp_arth

Comment: It used for legend only.. Are you sure you use a legend?

Comment: `the chart is not rendering` - it's not `css` issue..

Comment: @vp_arth dint know that, but i'm not using legends

Comment: I'm just trying to replicate the same as given in the angular charts examples @vp_arth

Comment: 1. check library is loaded; 2. check your dependencies included; 3. check your scope data is correct.

Comment: 4. check, you didn't forget about `ng-controller`; it's missed in the demo code

Comment: Did you find a solution. For me in local it works fine, but when I deply in production server, it does not render or apply styles.